# Database Insertition in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am new in CI.

I want to insert values into database. But data is not  inserted successfully into database. I have already created controller but the data is not inserted successfully.

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: You will need a model as well and to make sure your database.php config file has the correct settings. As a start point :)

Answer (score 0):

The codeigniter works in MVC framework i.e Model,View and controller (https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/mvc.html). In model all your DB queries goes in it. Controller works as a bridge between your view and model. In view your you create your web pages. Here is a simple example for insertion data in database

### form

```
<form action="controller/submitData" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

### controller

```
public function submitData()
{
  $this->load->model('yourModel');
  $data=$this->input->post();
  $this->yourModel->insertData($data);
}
```

### Model

```
public function insertData($data)
{
   $this->db->insert("tableName",array("fieldName"=>$data['name']));
   return true;
}
```